# In Elixir/Phoenix what does `as: :pages` do?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

In the Phoenix web framework for Elixir, what does the `as: :pages` in `get "/pages/:page", PageController, :show, as: :pages` do? And second, what is `as:`, a macro? A map?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `as:` option allows you to customized the named router helper functions that we generate to recreate the defined route. i.e from the docs:

The named helper can also be customized with the `:as` option. Given
  the route:

```
  get "/pages/:page", PageController, :show, as: :special_page
```

the named helper will be:

```
  MyApp.Router.Helpers.special_page_path(:show, "hello")
  "/pages/hello"
```

`as:` in this case is an option to the router macro, not a macro itself.

Comment: Looking at the docs I take it helpers are used for accessing a route from inside your code without going through the Router. Is that correct? E.g. if I want to re-route to another path?

Comment: @stoft the helper is a function that generates the path for you. So instead of hardcoding paths, you can use the helper which will generate the URL by interpolating arguments and also guaranteeing it actually exists. For example, let's suppose you rename "/pages/:page" to "/my/pages/:page". If you hardcoded URLs, you would now have broken links in your app. By using the helper, the URLs will be correct once you recompile your code. In case the URL is removed, you'd get a compilation error.